# In GitAhead, is there a way to change the UI color of the file status badges (A=added, D=deleted, M=modified), in difference between commits?

Tags: gitahead

I've tried to find a way to change those, modifying a custom theme file, but it looks like there is no direct scope for these badges.
They take the same color of the commit branch and tag badges.

I've done a quick mockup of what I would like to achieve: [Current vs Proposed colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVw1S.jpg).
It is similar to what Sourcetree does, and I think is very useful to assess changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment. from what i see in theme file it's possible to change color of badges but that color is shared between A,D,M badges and branches badges

```
theme['badge']     = {
  foreground       = {
    normal         = '#E1E5F2',
    selected       = '#2A82DA'
  },
  background       = {
    normal         = '#2A82DA', -- the default color
    selected       = '#E1E5F2', -- the color when a list item is selected
    conflicted     = '#DA2ADA', -- the color of conflicted items
    head           = '#52A500', -- a bolder color to indicate the HEAD
    notification   = '#8C2026'  -- the color of toolbar notifications badges
  }
}
```

normal - is for non active badge 
selected - for active badge

If you want it to be changed you should open an issue with feature request here: https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/issues

Comment: Thanks, I came to the same conclusion after exploring and fiddling with the theme file. I’ll open an issue, it looks like a low hanging UI fruit